# nanoFramework: Unable to send web request: SocketException - CLR_E_FAIL (1)

Tags: c#, httpclient, esp32, nanoframework

As I am not getting any help on the offical nanoFrameowork github page I thought maybe somebody here could help.

So I am using the nanoFramework on an ESP32 device and I  am trying to send a webrequest to a server on my network, but I'm getting the following:

> ++++ Exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException - CLR_E_FAIL (1) ++++
> ++++ Message:
> ++++ System.Net.Security.SslNative::SecureConnect [IP: 0000] ++++
> ++++ System.Net.Security.SslStream::Authenticate [IP: 0054] ++++
> ++++ System.Net.Security.SslStream::AuthenticateAsClient [IP: 000a] ++++
> ++++ System.Net.HttpWebRequest::EstablishConnection [IP: 027c] ++++
> ++++ System.Net.HttpWebRequest::SubmitRequest [IP: 001a] ++++
> ++++ System.Net.HttpWebRequest::GetRequestStream [IP: 0008] ++++
> ++++ System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker::Send [IP: 0013] ++++
> ++++ System.Net.Http.HttpClient::Send [IP: 006f] ++++
> ++++ System.Net.Http.HttpClient::Post [IP: 0011] ++++

My code:

```
private const string myCACertificate = @"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----   text of my cert removed for brevity -----END CERTIFICATE-----";

     private static  HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient()
     {
            HttpsAuthentCert = new X509Certificate(myCACertificate),
            SslProtocols = System.Net.Security.SslProtocols.Tls12
     };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyObject());
    StringContent strcontent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    string url = $"https://myserver:8788/api/path";

    var response = _httpClient.Post(url, strcontent);
```

The nanoframework is obviously more limited compared to 'full' .net.

It seems to be some kind of certificate issue with SSL, but I can't find any more details or better examples online, so don't really know why this doesn't work and what I need to do to get this working.

Comment: does your system has the correct date & time set? Are you sure that that root CA is the same as the one at the device you are connecting to? Are you using which fw version and which hardware? 
Also can you succesfully run the SecureClient_WiFi sample from here:https://github.com/nanoframework/Samples/tree/main/samples/SSL/SecureClient_WiFi?